# Android - Call an xml layout file in a class that extends View

Tags: android, android-view, android-event

I want to call my XML layout file in a class that extends view. I can't perform oncreate function in that because it does not extends Activity. My events are in the one class file and I am calling that class in another class file; but I want to perform those events on XML layout file.

Here is my code:

Demo.java

```
public class Demo extends Activity
{
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new another(this));
}
```

another.java

```
public class another extends View
{
      public anotherView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        init();
    }

    public anotherView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public anotherView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);  

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
       ...
        ..
        ..
}
```

And XML file

```
abc.xml
..
..
```

How to do it?

Comment: you want your class can used in the XML like the android view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add an item to your View you could always inflate it.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)    
getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ABC, null);
addView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to get an item from your XML 
you should call
`[yourviewType]View v1 = (Cast-to-type-of-view)context.findViewById(R.id.idOfView);`

Example :
`TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.aboutText);`

is this what you need ?